# Discord Python, creating a Channel and moving directly people to it?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I already created this code:

```
#Creating the Channel
        guild = bot.get_guild(771495836701425725)
        await guild.create_voice_channel(f"Rainbow Ranked for {members2move}", category=940356081891287110, user_limit=members2move)
        print("Created a new Voice Channel!")
        print(f"Moving {members2move} People.\n{string_message_split}")
        async def move(ctx, channel : discord.VoiceChannel)
        bot.move_member(person_to_move, channel_to_move_person_to_move_to)
```

But i dont know how i can get the ID from the Channel i recently created

Comment: your naming convention is so... strange

Comment: @ŁukaszKwieciński at least it's descriptive :)

Answer (score 1):

create_voice_channel returns the channel and you can access a channel's id,
apparently you have to pass a channel object to the move_member function not just the id

```
#Creating the Channel
        guild = bot.get_guild(771495836701425725)
        v_channel = await guild.create_voice_channel(f"Rainbow Ranked for {members2move}", category=940356081891287110, user_limit=members2move)
        print("Created a new Voice Channel!")
        print(f"Moving {members2move} People.\n{string_message_split}")
        async def move(ctx, channel : discord.VoiceChannel)
          person_to_move.move_to(v_channel)
```

Comment: Thank u very much, i will try it as soon as Discord works again. Do u prolly know, why bot.move_member doesnt work? so it marks "move_member" and says: Unresolved attribut reference "move_member" in class bot

Comment: I just learned that it was changed, the method is now move_to() that you call on a member. I have edited my answer appropriately. Here is the reference [move_to](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member.move_to).

Comment: Oh okay, thank u very much man :D

Comment: I tried also something:
guild = bot.get_guild(771495836701425725)
            message_authorid = await guild.get_member_named(name=message.author)
            user_ids2move = user_ids.extend(message)
            print(message_authorid)

But when i try it, somehting with member has no len shows up, but idk why

Comment: i forget to mention, that i want to get the ID from a name

Comment: I didn't quite understand what you meant, but you can get the author id with message.author.id. The error is probably caused by the name parameter, you are trying to pass the Member object instead of the name. Here's the reference for the [Member](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=member#discord.Member) class.

Comment: thanks a lot, u helped me very much

Answer (score 0):

When you create a channel, [the channel is returned by the `create_voice_channel` function](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=returns#discord.Guild.create_voice_channel). You should be able to get the channel (and so the ID of the channel) like this:

```
    guild = bot.get_guild(771495836701425725)
    channel = await guild.create_voice_channel(f"Rainbow Ranked for {members2move}", category=940356081891287110, user_limit=members2move)
    print(f"Created a new Voice Channel; it has the ID {channel.id}!")
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import os

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='>')

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Log : "+str(client.user))

@client.event
async def on_voice_state_update(member, before, after):
    if member.guild.id == guild id:
        channel = after.channel
        try:
            if before.channel.members == [] and not before.channel.id == channel id:
                if before.channel.category_id == category id:
                    await before.channel.delete()
        except:
            pass
            if channel.id == channel id:
                    channel = await after.channel.clone(name=f"{member.name}'s Channel")
                    await member.move_to(channel)

client.run("token")
```